# Difference of two symmetric, positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $q \times p$ matrices of rank $q < p$.

Moreover, $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ are $p \times p$ diagonal matrices with all diagonal elements are strictly positive.

In this case, can
$$
D_{1} - A^{\operatorname{T}}A = D_{2} - B^{\operatorname{T}}B
$$
guarantee $D_{1} = D_{2}$ and $A = B$?

I think this is not true, but finding counter example is quite hard to me. I am also curious about conditions which make the above equation valid.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: ...but if $A = B$, then $A^\mathsf{T} A - B^\mathsf{T} B = A^\mathsf{T} A - A^\mathsf{T} A = 0 \neq D$. Typo?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not true that $A^TA = B^TB$ implies that $A = B$. So, let's stick to the weaker condition of 
$$
D_1 - A^TA = D_2 - B^TB \implies D_1 = D_2, \quad A^TA = B^TB.
$$
Even so, the statement does not hold. Take $p=1,q=2,$ and 
$$
D_1 = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}, \quad D_2 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad A = \pmatrix{1&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&1}.
$$

Comment: I've corrected the question! Sorry to confuse you :)

Comment: See my latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true: take 
$$D_1 = D_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0&5\end{bmatrix}, ~ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, ~ B = -A$$
As seen, this equation almost never implies that $A = B$, because $A = -B$ will satisfy the equation too. Even discounting for this trivial counterexample, and even if $D_1 = D_2$, it is not guaranteed that $A = B$. The relation
$$M = A ^T A = B^T B$$
is far from implying $A = B$. In fact, any spectral decomposition $Q D Q^T$ of $M$ can be used to find a matrix $C$ such that $C^T C = M$. Indeed, any $C = Q \sqrt{D}$ (recall $\sqrt{D}$ is well-defined as $M$ is positive semi-definite) will fit the bill. The spectral decomposition is not unique, and hence neither is $A$ or $B$.

In a nutshell: this equation doesn't come close to implying $A = B$, much less $D_1 = D_2$ *and* $A = B$.